# Ghostscript mangles umlauts when reading PDFs

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I use this on Linux

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=txtwrite -o res.txt 1.pdf
```

when extracting text from some hundred PDFs, however, umlauts and other special chars up to ASCII 255 get mangled. Any ideas?

cf https://archive.org/download/bnmm_gmx_1/1.pdf (contains two "ä")

[image: screenshot of mangled text fragment]

Partial translation table: (the last one and all other special letters of the Turkish alphabet are mangled using non-printable chars, else I could help myself)

```
ä = À¤
é = À©
ç = À§
```

[image: screenshot of mangled text fragment]

[image: screenshot of geany text editor]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it ought to work as the fonts have a ToUnicode CMap. I'd suggest you open a bug report.

Note, you are not using ASCII, the embedded and subset fonts are CIDFonts and the CMap in use creates 2-byte character codes (though ridiculously all the high bytes are 0). But for example, the space is actually encoded as character code 0x0003, the '0' is code 0x0013 etc.

By the way a simple example would be useful, its quite hard to pick out the accented glyphs from the regular text in this file.

Comment: Thanks, I added a screenshot. As for the bug report, ok, but I was hoping for some helpful additional flag or something. Do you know about some other tools for PDF text extraction that I could use with bash?

Comment: I'm using http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer for python now, works fine with German and Turkish special chars. I'm still disappointed with ghostscript, though, I'd like to stick to basic tools.

Comment: I don't need the screenshot, I can read German. But when trying to see how the text is being processed its a lot easier to debug if there are only say half a dozen characters instead of several hundred, only a couple of which demonstrate a problem. Having to debug past dozens, or hundreds of characters which work means there's a high chance of missing the one which doesn't. The reason I suggested opening a bug report is because it looks like it should work. If it doesn't that means its a bug, and I'm afraid we software engineers haven't come up with the magic Turn off bugs' flag yet :-)

Comment: Ok, I told them about it and they asked me to report it: https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=697932

Comment: The 'problem' is that the output is UTF-8 and you seem to be expecting ASCII. Not only that, you are expecting 'extended' ASCII, where the characters beyond 127 (0x7f) have specific meanings. These are language dependent, so the output actually writes UTF-8 encoded Unicode code points. If you use a UTF-* aware text editor it should work fine, it does for me.

Comment: In fact the documentation (file:///D:/ghostpdl/doc/VectorDevices.htm#TXT) even says so. You can get UCS2 including a BOM if you set -dTextFormat=2. You can't get extended ASCII though.

Comment: -dTextFormat=2 does work, though I'd like to stick with UTF-8. I added a screenshot of my text editor (Geany) that is UTF-* aware. python/pdfminer gets it just right. My problem is solved alright, I'm just being curious...

Comment: No idea, really. You would need to ask someone about the specific application to figure out why its getting it wrong. The text output is raw UTF-8, so it can only be that the application is making some kind of default assumption; no idea what.